# YQL for countries

Tags: web-services, geolocation, yql, country

How would I query to get a country's name using the Latitude and Longitude positions using YQL? Or better could I be pointed to find out the table's columns?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer I was looking for was :

```
SELECT * FROM geo.placefinder WHERE text=\"{0}\" and gflags=\"r
```

Text is the latitude and longitude e.g. -27,28

This will return a xml with country's information.

Comment: This `SELECT` statement doesn't work as is and I'm not sure what would fix it `\-:`

Comment: You need to encode the select query and append it to the url.

Comment: Oh I mean it doesn't even work in the YQL console. The escaped double quotes are probably a problem, I'm not sure if {0} is some kind of template? And the final "r" is missing a closing quote. It results in this error: `Query syntax error(s) [line 1:41 no viable alternative at character '&amp;amp;#92;',line 1:63 mismatched character ' ' expecting '"']`. [YQL console link](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20geo.placefinder%20WHERE%20text%3D%5C%22%7B0%7D%5C%22%20and%20gflags%3D%5C%22r)

Comment: In the console you need to write out SELECT * FROM geo.placefinder WHERE text="-27,28" and gflags="R"

Answer (score 0):

The above query does work, but let me take you through all the steps.

Constructing the url query to yahoo and creating a request.

```
string url = string.Format("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("SELECT * FROM geo.placefinder WHERE text=\"-27,28\" and gflags=\"r\""));
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
```

Getting the response data:

```
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

    geo.CountryName = doc.SelectSingleNode("./query/results/Result/country").InnerText;
    geo.AlphaCode = doc.SelectSingleNode("./query/results/Result/countrycode").InnerText;
    geo.City = doc.SelectSingleNode("./query/results/Result/city").InnerText;
    geo.State = doc.SelectSingleNode("./query/results/Result/state").InnerText;        

}
```